# What is the current development status of Transparent OLEDs?

Tags: touchscreen, oled

As far as I can see there are some [working prototypes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdn_nZzvQL8), but has this technology reached the market in a stable way?

Does anybody know what's the current status of the TOLED technology?

Also do you think would be possible to add a capacitive touch layer on top of a TOLED?

Comment: To whom it may concern: I reviewed the question and I don't think it's a shopping question, despite the OP asking for specific vendors. I think he only wants that information as evidence of the state of the technology. So I wouldn't close the question as [off-topic](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Oh, no, no it's absolutely not a shopping question: I'm more asking if this sort of technology reached the market in a stable way. Not asking for specific vendors. (gonna rephrase)

Comment: Right, that's what I'm getting at. But it's always good to make sure the question isn't classified as a shopping question if you want it answered here. I was tempted to edit it myself, but then I thought I would be changing its meaning too much. Your edit was excellent in that regard, by the way.

Comment: http://www.4dsystems.com.au/product/uTOLED_20_G2/

Comment: http://www.udcoled.com/default.asp?contentID=591 ask for their roadmap

Comment: There's a few mentions of it being sold on this [link](http://www.oled-info.com/hands-4d-systems-2-transparent-pmoled-panel) and others, but I haven't seen any real places to buy it.

Comment: Today's technology has made this question obsolete. VTC.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung has shown several different transparent OLED displays in the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYQUCpLlc8U).

When they will come to the masses remains a question. One company that is close to providing transparent OLED displays to the public is [Planar](http://www.planar.com/innovations/transparent-oled/).

Adding a capacitive touch film on top of the display would be fairly easy, as this technology has been around since the 70s. I don't see any reason why adding a capacitive touch film would be troublesome for OLED displays.

Comment: I'm not sure that the transparency will be as useful as all that. The other things like colour gamut will be. Regarding transparency, while it looks cool and in movies allows us to see the actor's face while they work on their data, seeing through the display would just be distracting. It's bad enough having a cat in front (they are all programmed by nature to seek to obscure anything a person is paying attention to, especially screens). Personally I now think near future we're going to be getting used to entire walls as screens, affordable to the masses.